# How to convert a boolean expression into product of sums?

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations, boolean-algebra

Let's take an example f= a'b + a'c' + abc.
How to convert this boolean expression into product of sum?

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider the function:

```
f= a'b + a'c' + abc
```

Take complement:

```
f'= (a'b + a'c' + abc)'
f'= ((a'b)' . (a'c')' . (abc)' )
f'= (a+b') . (a+c) . (a'+b'+c')
f'= (a+b'c) . (a'+b'+c')
f'= ab'+ac'+a'b'c+b'c
```

Take complement again:

```
f''=(ab'+ac'+a'b'c+b'c)'
f''=f=((ab')'(ac')' (a'b'c)' (b'c)' )
f= (a'+b) (a'+c) (a+b+c') (b+c')
```

This is how we can convert a given boolean expression into a product of sum.